# Need to create nested objects in javascript linking 3 user input arrays to create tree like pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If there are 3 arrays,

```
var a=[1,2,3];
var b=[1.1,1.2,'',2.1,2.2,2.3,'',3.1,3.2,3.3];
var c=['xyz','abc',' ','uvw',' ','opq','rst','cde',' ','hij',' ','stu','wxy','nop',' ','def',' ','fgh'];
```

elements should be linked such that `{key:1, val:{key:1.1,val:['xyz','abc']},{key:1, val:{key:1.2,val:['uvw']}`.
The elements in arrays b and c are separated by empty char "" and space " ", resp. I need a way to create nested associative arrays for tree like pattern.
I linked 2 arrays in the following manner. I need it for 3 arrays now.

```
<p id="ext">Extended: </p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var a=[1,2,3,4];
    var b = [1.1,1.2,1.3,'',2.1,2.2,'',3.1,3.2,3.3,'',4.1,'',5.1,5.2,'',6.1,6.2,''];
    //var arr = [];
    var obj = {};
    $('#ini').append(JSON.stringify(obj));
    //var i = 0, j = 0
    var j = 0; var bArr= [];
    var soln = {};
    for(i=0;i<b.length;i++){
        if(b[i]==''){                
            bArr=[];
            $('#ext').append(JSON.stringify(obj));
            if(j==a.length){
                var elem = 'undefined';
                $.extend(obj,{key: elem, val:bArr});
            }
            ++j;
            continue;
        }
        else{
            console.log(i);
            //console.log(j);
            var elem = a[j];
            bArr.push(b[i]);
            $.extend(obj,{key: elem, val:bArr});
            //j++;
        }
        //soln.key = elem;
        //soln.val = bArr;
    }
    //$('#ext').append(JSON.stringify(obj));
</script>
```

Comment: please add the wanted result and the code, you tried. please have a look here, too [mcve]

Comment: This seems like a very confusing data structure. I mean, you're making an object that contains a bunch of other objects where each one has only two properties (literally `key` and `val`). The whole structure seems odd and difficult to work with. I'd look at making it much simpler and more logical

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return the combined object of the other items with an index for every nested array and loop until a stop marker is found, then push to the inner array. Increment the last index after the loop as well for the next item.

```js
var data1 = [1, 2, 3],
    data2 = [1.1, 1.2, '', 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, '', 3.1, 3.2, 3.3],
    data3 = ['xyz', 'abc', ' ', 'uvw', ' ', 'opq', 'rst', 'cde', ' ', 'hij', ' ', 'stu', 'wxy', 'nop', ' ', 'def', ' ', 'fgh'],
    index2 = 0,
    index3 = 0,
    result = data1.map(function (a) {
        var o1 = { key: a, val: [] }, o2, o3;
        while (index2 < data2.length && data2[index2] !== '') {
            o2 = { key: data2[index2], val: [] };
            while (index3 < data3.length && data3[index3] !== ' ') {
                o2.val.push(data3[index3]);
                index3++;
            }
            index3++;
            o1.val.push(o2);
            index2++;
        }
        index2++;
        return o1;
    });

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks this exactly what I need. Can you tell me how to display these results on a browser in an html element